# Assign git commit to github issue manually

Tags: github

It is possible to assign existing commit to issue without using auto commit + issue integration (e.g. fixes #XXX, closed #XXX, etc. in commit title)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a fully satisfactory answer, but I noticed if we paste a link to the commit into comment, github automatically will add it as link-reference to it as a short hash.

input:

```
https://github.com/user/Repository/commit/a49c5c587185d3bee80a32e7fc4f9ea4e94289a8
```

output:

```
a49c5c5
```

Comment: Accepted because for not better solution.

Answer (score 7):

Go on your **commit** and comment it with the *number of your issue** preceded by an hashtag (#6 for example). The commit will then be "referenced" in the issue timeline.

This is not the same as integrating the commit directly, but it gets closer to simply comment on the issue with the commit hash (which is also an alternative).

Comment: This is actually a better solution than posting the commit hash as a comment.

Comment: Note that the author of commit will get a notification with the added comment. If using the accepted alternative the issue author (and subscribers) will get a notification.